# In bash script, how to generate a random string

Tags: bash, ssh, osx-yosemite, bash-scripting

I need to generate many random alphanumeric strings, which also use capital letters. It needs to start with 3 characters (e.g. Dk6) and then, with a while loop, go up to about 9 characters (e.g. D7H3j8Sjx). Also, I'm using sshpass 
and I need to check when it's the correct password, then stop.
I know that to guess the password, it would take a very long time, but it would also help if it guessed it by going aaa, aab, aac, aad... aaz, aa1 etc.

Comment: Which OS/distribution and version?

Comment: @Cyrus OS X Yosemite 10.10.3

Comment: Somewhat related: a random password generator with more complex requirements than yours is discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665389/random-password-generator-bash).

Comment: Have you ever heard of John the Ripper? http://www.openwall.com/john/

Answer (score 4):

This function

```
  function letter() {
    s=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxwyz
    p=$(( $RANDOM % 26))        echo -n ${s:$p:1}
  }
```

generates a random letter. You can substitute *abc...* for the list of characters you wish to use, count them, and substitute their number to the *26* in line 3.

Comment: how would I use this to find an sshpass password

Comment: @Jacob_ For what you want to do,it is perhaps best to use John the Ripper.

Comment: i don't know how to use john the ripper, even after looking through various tutorials

Comment: The function can be somewhat reduced, and needn't require the user to count the length of `$s` manually:  `letter() { printf -v s '%s' {a..z} ; echo ${s:$((RANDOM % ${#s})):1}; }`